# Accuracy of JavaScript time over a period of a few hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, time

I need to code myself a mini, locally running HTML5 + JavaScript app, which I will use as a timer to time a person performing [squats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squat_(exercise)).

The idea is simple: When I press **A** on the keyboard, it will store the current time with seconds and miliseconds into a local table as a repetition start. When I press **B**, it will store the current time as a repetition end.

What I'm not 100% sure about is how reliable the JavaScript timestamp really is. What is my best bet here? Here are a few ideas:

- run it on the latest version of Chrome
- disable the internet connection, so that the OS will not sync/change its current time

Is there anything else I should be careful about?

I don't need the time to be absolutely exact, only relatively; meaning that the last timestamp minus the first timestamp will yield the real time taken to perform the whole session. I don't care to know exactly at what time it started.

Comment: If you trust system clock on your computer you can trust the JavaScript timestamps too

Comment: How do you want to determine the time? If you simply do `Date.now()` at the start and at the end of the exercise, I'm quite sure it'll be accurate enough for this purpose.

Comment: So all I gotta do is to make sure that OS never changes the time during the session, right?

Comment: @Richard Rodriguez If you asked me I would say "yes". Although I can't understand how you going ensure that.

Comment: If you're worried about the user spoofing your program, you might want to add some extra checks such as that the `Date.now()` is ever-increasing (e.g. by using `setInterval`).

Comment: You seem to worry about a 0.00001% accuracy issue. Are you sure it's worth it ? I think you're wasting our time.

Comment: Calm down, guys, I'm not trying to waste anyone's time and I'm also not worrying about 0.00001% accuracy issues. I was just not sure whether it won't cause 1 - 2 second difference over more hours. I don't use JavaScript's time much. I always rely on PHP's ``microtime()``, which I cannot use here.

Comment: Richard, the comparison of the start + end time will only be as inaccurate as the client computer's system clock - so, pretty darn accurate. If you want an implementation that is truly independent of the  client's system clock, you could call a time web service (http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now).. it's a super simple AJAX call if you are actually concerned about the edge case of your system clock being changed while your code is running. No judgements here, just pitching in that you are not dealing with some 'drifting' clock when calling Date.now() at the beginning & end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're retrieving the system time in Javascript with something like `Date.now()` in order to measure the time between two events, then that will be exactly as accurate as the system time is on the local computer.  How exactly accurate that is will depend entirely upon the clock in the local system and whether there are any changes to the system time during the measurement period.

If there are no changes to the system time (such as a clock sync with an external source), then most system clocks are pretty darn accurate these days.  Measuring an event that takes minutes would likely be accurate within a few milliseconds which is more accuracy than you can achieve by marking start and stop with just a keypress anyway since the precision on exactly when the key is pressed relative to the start and stop of the event is certainly not better than several hundred milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the information I needed to know!